# Python Transpose Matrix Giving me the wrong python

Tags: python

I wrote a transpose matrix function however, when I try to run it the values inside the output becomes the same in the end. Attached there is a picture of the output. My code is also commented.

```
def transpose(any_matrix):
    _row = len(any_matrix)
    _col = len(any_matrix[0])
    temp_matrix = []
    #multiplies [0] by the number of rows (old) to create new row
    temp_row = [0]*_row
    #creates matrix with number of columns as rows  
    for x in range(_col):
        temp_matrix += [temp_row]
    for r in range(len(any_matrix)):
        for c in range(len(any_matrix[0])):
            value = any_matrix[r][c]
            temp_matrix[c][r] = value
return temp_matrix

a = [[4, 5, 6], [7,8,9]]
print(transpose(a))

    #input [[4,5,6]
    #       [7,8,9]]

    #correct answer [   [4,7],
    #                   [5,8],
    #                   [6,9]   ]
```

I prefer not to use other libraries such as numpy etc.
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qVMz.png)

Comment: I'm not getting the same output: `[[6, 9], [6, 9], [6, 9]]` still looking for an answer though

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly . The rows of your `temp_matrix` are all the same `temp_row` list.

Comment: The idiomatic way to transpose a rectangular list of lists, e.g.,
`a = [list(range(n,n*6,n)) for n in range(1,12)]` is
`a_transpose = [list(col) for col in zip(*a)]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior is more fully explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly), so I recommend you take a look.

when you use the line `temp_matrix += [temp_row]`, you are adding the list object `temp_row` to the array (three times in this case.)

When you say

```
temp_matrix[c][r] = value
```

the value is overwritten in the `temp_row` object, because `temp_matrix[c]` ***is the same object as*** `temp_row`, so when you go to print out the whole temp_matrix, it prints out what it is: 3 references to the same matrix.

Using the `list.copy()` method should get around this undesired effective pointer-passing by adding a new `list` object (that is a copy of the `temp_row`) to `temp_matrix`.
Here's some working code:

```
def transpose(any_matrix):
    _row = len(any_matrix)
    _col = len(any_matrix[0])
    temp_matrix = []
    #multiplies [0] by the number of rows (old) to create new row
    temp_row = [0]*_row
    #creates matrix with number of columns as rows  
    for x in range(_col):
        temp_matrix += [temp_row.copy()]
    for r in range(len(any_matrix)):
        for c in range(len(any_matrix[0])):
            value = any_matrix[r][c]
            temp_matrix[c][r] = value
    return temp_matrix

a = [[4, 5, 6], [7,8,9]]
print(transpose(a))

    #input [[4,5,6]
    #       [7,8,9]]

    #correct answer [   [4,7],
    #                   [5,8],
    #                   [6,9]   ]
```

Comment: OP could also instantiate temp_matrix as a matrix of zeros and it'll solve the problem

Comment: This is true. I wanted to try to explain this behavior as well.

Comment: Thank you very much I've been cracking my head at this for a while.

Comment: I remember the first time I came across this. It happens in dictionaries too. Keep a look out.