# Python array value allocation glitch

Tags: python, arrays, list

**Solved, thanks to everyone for their help!**
My array generation code was referencing the same array, so edits would apply to whole columns instead of specific points.

I'm making a few functions I can use in future programs in Python to do with arrays, such as defining them and displaying them. However, I came across a strange bug or glitch while trying to set values in order in an array from left to right. For some reason, when the program sets values on the last y value, (or actually on any value,) it sets that value for the whole column instead for just one, even though I only have 2 loops. Here's my code:

```
def gen(xLen, yLen, fill = 0):
    mainArr = list()
    secArr = list()
    for i in range(xLen):
        secArr.append(fill)
    for i in range(yLen):
        mainArr.append(secArr)
    return mainArr

def sums(xLen, yLen):
    newArr = gen(xLen, yLen)
    a = 0
    for y in range(yLen):
        for x in range(xLen):
            newArr[y][x] = a
            print(str(x) + ", " + str(y) + " = " + str(a)) #For debugging, what the array SHOULD contain
            a += 1
    return newArr
```

(Just run this with `print(sums(5, 5))`)

Instead of returning with `[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], ... [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]]`, it returns with a list full of `[20, 21, 22, 23, 24]` and I really don't know why.

I don't want to append a new list to another list with values already in them, for example `arr.append([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])`, because the array is already generated.
Why doesn't this work??? It's been bugging me for weeks!

Comment: It's not clear to me what function you expect to return a list of lists, or if that's even what you're trying to get. Could you edit your question to focus more on _clearly_ explaining your problem and what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`secArr` is a reference to a list.
So in `gen` you are actually placing `n` times the same reference to `secArr` in `mainArr`.

Add a `print(newArr)` in the for to verify this.

You can run `newArr[0][1] = 1` to see how all the inner lists are affected.

You can solve this by creating a copy of `secArr` before appending it to `mainArr` in `gen`, like this:

```
mainArr.append(secArr[:])
```

More on the topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744113/python-list-by-value-not-by-reference) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference).

Comment: This answer is good, but I would actually suggest doing `mainArr.append(secArr.copy())` - I feel that the explicit copy makes it more obvious what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

While Julian Peller's answer answers your specific question, I would propose a way cleaner and more pythonic way to do your tasks:

```
def gen2(xLen, yLen, fill=0):
    return [[fill for x in range(xLen)] for y in range(yLen)]

def sums2(xLen, yLen):
    return [[y*yLen+x for x in range(xLen)] for y in range(yLen)]
```

These functions are using list comprehensions which are more readable and avoid making errors like yours for example

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing the same effects as the person who asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52544561/4802259). I hope my answer, and the other linked answers can help you understand why this is happening, and how to fix it.